# Minimum Privileges for Nexus Private Docker Registry

Tags: docker, nexus

I have setup a private docker registry on Nexus over http and I am able to pull/push with no issues when I 'docker login' using the nexus administrator account. To maintain security best practices I do not want to be using an administrator account simply to pull and push images so I want to make another account for that purpose.

I have created a role is nexus and granted it 'add'  privileges but these seem to be insufficient for the docker login command. Which other privileges are required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a bit of trial and error but it seems that at a minimum you need the following:

1. Add
2. Edit
3. Read

In my case specifically, I used the pre-built repository-view type add, edit and read privileges for my repository.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to grant the nx-repository-view--*  privilege for the docker repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this privileges are bit too broad, I want to limit which are assigned.